# pop Instruction not supported in 64-bit mode using NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, 32bit-64bit

I'm working on a more indepth hello world using NASM [following this tutorial](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~if817/arquivos/asmtut/quickstart.html) (section 4). This tutorial essentially teaches you how to handle command line input.

This is the snippet of the code in question:

```
section .text
        global _start

_start:
        pop     ebx     ; arg count
        pop     ebx     ; arg[0] the program name
        pop     ebx     ; arg[1-n] the remainder of the args
                        ; must each be indiviually popped
```

The code errors out during compilation with `error: instruction not supported in 64-bit mode` referring to the 3 pop instructions above. [Upon viewing the docs](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall02/V22.0201-001/nasm_doc_html/nasmdocb.html#section-B.4.244) it seems that this code only works for 32-bit systems.

Is there a 64-bit `pop` instruction? Does anyone have a 64 bit tutorial using `pop` that I can look at?

Comment: You do realize the tutorial is for 32-bit?  I believe you can generate 32-bit code by setting the output format to `elf32` rather than `elf`, which should allow you to follow this tutorial even on a 64-bit machine...

Comment: @Aedin - Yes, you should stay in 32-bit mode if following that tutorial. Not only are the register names different when using 64 bits, so are also the calling conventions. Just replacing the `pop`'s is unlikely to work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, the 64-bit `pop` instruction is...  POP.  :-)  You need to use it against 64-bit registers though (like `rbx`).

Comment: When I replaced with `POP.`, getting this error: "_error: parser: instruction expected_" I'm using `nasm -f elf64 myfile.asm` myfile includes this line: `POP. eax;`

Comment: @hasany Remove the "." as it is causing a syntax error.  It should just be "POP EAX"

Comment: @hasany You may have a syntax error before that instruction then.  Or perhaps you are missing a required assembler directive.  I'd recommend opening you own question on this site, with the minimum source code required to cause the error included.

Answer (score 1):

basically you can convert it into 64bit by replacing eax to rax (same goes for all other registers)